# SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

i have one issue with my object 
i have use memored library in node js to store data

this is my functions for store data

```
memored.store('driverList', list);
```

and this is for get that store list 
this is code

```
memored.read('driverList', function(err, list) {
    var driver  = list;
});
```

after get list is like in example

```js
var list = [ null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,  
  null,
  null,
  '{"phonenumber":"123123","client":{"index":"103.240.34.250:61667","sock":{"_connecting":false,"_handle":{"fd":20,"writeQueueSize":0,"owner":"[Circular]","reading":true},"_readableState":{"highWaterMark":16384,"buffer":[],"length":0,"pipes":null,"pipesCount":0,"flowing":false,"ended":false,"endEmitted":false,"reading":true,"calledRead":true,"sync":false,"needReadable":true,"emittedReadable":false,"readableListening":false,"objectMode":false,"defaultEncoding":"utf8","ranOut":false,"awaitDrain":0,"readingMore":false,"decoder":null,"encoding":null},"readable":true,"domain":null,"_events":{},"_maxListeners":10,"_writableState":{"highWaterMark":16384,"objectMode":false,"needDrain":false,"ending":false,"ended":false,"finished":false,"decodeStrings":false,"defaultEncoding":"utf8","length":0,"writing":false,"sync":false,"bufferProcessing":false,"writecb":null,"writelen":0,"buffer":[],"errorEmitted":false},"writable":true,"allowHalfOpen":false,"onend":null,"destroyed":false,"bytesRead":24,"_bytesDispatched":2,"_pendingData":null,"_pendingEncoding":"","server":{"domain":null,"_events":{},"_maxListeners":10,"_connections":1,"connections":1,"_handle":{"fd":17,"writeQueueSize":0,"owner":"[Circular]"},"_usingSlaves":false,"_slaves":[],"allowHalfOpen":false,"_connectionKey":"4:0.0.0.0:25001"},"_peername":{"address":"103.240.34.250","family":"IPv4","port":61667},"_consuming":true},"_actualLength":0,"_msg":[2,114,116,101,115,116,64,103,109,97,105,108,46,99,111,109,124,114,97,118,105,110,97],"_written":0,"driver":"[Circular]"},"online":true,"onDuty":true,"latitude":0,"longitude":0,"vehicle":"Sedan","id":1056,"fullname":"test01 test01","pendingRides":{},"ride":null,"rpm":"0","licensePlate":"dri123","logintime":1471025147}' ]

var data   = list.filter(Boolean).shift();
var list = JSON.parse(data)
    
console.log(list.id)
for (var elementId in list) {
                driver = list[elementId];
                
                if(!driver.online || !driver.onDuty) continue;
                driverLists.push({
                    id: driver.id,
                    latitude: driver.latitude,
                    longitude: driver.longitude,
                    fullname: driver.fullname,
                    rpm: driver.rpm,
                    vehicle: driver.vehicle,
                    licensePlate: driver.licensePlate,
                    logintime: driver.logintime
                });
            }
 console.log(driverLists);
```

i want driver.id from this object but when i try to get its get me undefined and i also try with JSON.parse(value) so its get me SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,

so how can i get id 
please give me if you have proper solution for this issue

Answer (score 0):

`driver` is an array, and `driver[15]` is a string.

So perhaps you want `JSON.parse(driver[15]).id`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `driver` is an array, seen by the `[]` brackets in the output, and the object is really a string.

First get rid of all the `null` values you for some reason have, then get the string and parse it, then get the value

```
var data   = driver.filter(Boolean).shift();
var parsed = JSON.parse(data);
var id     = parsed.id;
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/hwch1gaz/)

Comment: @trusharwidetech - you're looking for things that aren't there. You have a single driver, yet you're trying to loop with `for ..in`, which won't work -> **https://jsfiddle.net/aarLcLe9/**

Comment: when i have more then 1 driver at that time is work?

Comment: Sure, if the data is completely different, and you have an array of drivers, it probably does work ?